# Entity Framework : interrupt running SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, savechanges

I have a unique `ObjectContext`, on which I perform a `SaveChanges()`. This operation takes some time (~60 seconds).
This operation is executed in a thread.

My user have a "Cancel" button on the screen.
I'm able to stop the thread, but if the `SaveChanges()` has already started I can't find anyway to cancel it.
In fact I found no way to access the underlying transaction (I also have an Isolation level issue : this operation locks almost all tables in database, so the application cannot be used by other users).

Would it work if I closed the underlying connection ? The EF won't be able to send a `Rollback` instruction but I guess the database would perform it anyway, no ?

I've seen that I could use `TransactionScope` but it needs to access DTC and my host is not really performant when it comes to edit server/network configuration.
So if a "Entity Framework" solution exist I'd prefer that one.

Answer (score 0):

is your SaveChanges() saving multiple updates? Is it possible to update then save each individually?

Then, if you are inside a transaction, and user cancels, you'd have more granularity in your saves.